# firebase authentication sendVerificationEmail() task taking forever

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, kotlin-android-extensions

I am new to firebase authentication and I am implementing a log-in flow using `FirebaseUI` in my android app. As part of the flow I am sending the user a verification email and have a "send again" button for sending another email in case the user didn't get the first one. I am sending the emails using this method:

```
fun sendVerificationEmail() {
    if (!isSignedIn()) {
        verificationEmailFailed("cannot send verification email. FirebaseAuth user was null.")
    } else {
        //isSignedIn() returned 'true', so currentUser should not be null
        auth.currentUser!!.apply {
            sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d(TAG, "verification email successfully sent to $email")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    verificationEmailFailed(
                        "FAILED to send verification email to $email: ${it.message}", it)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I call this method (after the user registered for the first time) everything works perfectly and the email is sent almost immediately. Now I am doing some manual testing and I want to test that my UI updates correctly when sending the email failed. I am doing this by turning off the internet before the user clicks the "send again" button. This would be the test flow:

1. Register new user, but don't verify it.
2. UI will update saying "you must verify your email to continue" and the "send again" button would show (all good).
3. Turn off the internet (simulating a situation where the email could not be sent and the task will fail).
4. Click the "send again" button.

### Expected Result

The task will immediately fail and the `OnFailureListener` will trigger.

### Actual Result

The task takes **multiple minutes** to process until eventually the `OnFailureListener` will trigger.

Is this a bug? Bad handling of timeout for the `sendEmailVerification` task?

Is there anything I can do other than  monitor the network state myself?

Comment: While the email delivery may take time, calling the API should not take long. Can you include some logging in your code that shows the timing, and then include the updated code and its logcat output in your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i can try. but note that its not the sending of the email that takes time, but the completion of the `Task` object and the triggering of the failure listener. in fact, the email should not be sent at all in the scenario im describing (because the `Task` cannot possibly succeed without an internet connection)

Comment: I ran into this issue as well and ended up overriding the smtp settings with sendgrid instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem: unfortunately I did not find a proper solution so I ended up manually checking the connection state before starting the sign-in process

Answer (score 0):

This may be the expected behavior, as the task tries to deliver the call to the server repeatedly before failing. This is is done as many users experience regular brief drops of their internet connection, and failing the API call would lead to a worse experience.

If you want to handle the offline experience differently, you'll have to check the internet connectivity yourself before calling the Firebase API.

Comment: its perfectly fine that the task retries to send the email. but i think the timeout should not be several minutes. is there a way to verify that this is simply due to a super long timeout?